# Excel Formula / VBA

Tags: excel

I wonder if you can help, I am working on a spread sheet where Column B is populated with data.

What I want to be able to do is to say (using b3 as an example)

If `B3` is populated then `A2+1`. I am using this formula in cell `a3`:

```
=IF(B2 > 0, A2 +1)
```

which gives me the result I want but when I hit a blank cell in B it starts the count over again. so I tried:

```
=IF(B2 > 0,A2 +1,A1 + 1)
```

but that counts my blank spaces. I need it to continue the count from the cell above without counting blank spaces. I have also tried applying the formula through pentaho to no avail.

It would be good if the formula actively looked and populated Column A instead of a manual formula having to be copied.

I have also used the `COUNTIF` function but I don't seem to be able to get it to work.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With column **B** like:

[image]

Place a starting value in **A2** and in **A3** enter:

```
=IF(B2>0,MAX($A$1:A2)+1,"")
```

and copy down:

[image]

Comment: If its work then please accept it as an answer by clicking the tick mark below the Down arrow and also you can up vote it by clicking up arrow.